# Javascript - Calendar Flip animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create a calendar wherein upon clicking a particular date, the calendar should flip over to reveal details of a specific reservation. While the calendar interface appears perfectly on the webpage, the flip animation does not work and I cant seem to figure out why. I must add that I found most of this code on codepen and am modifying it based on my preference. I have attached my code breakdown below. I would greatly appreciate any advice and help. Thanks!:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
var app = {
  settings: {
    container: $(".calendar"),
    calendar: $(".front"),
    days: $(".weeks span"),
    form: $(".back"),
    input: $(".back input"),
    buttons: $(".back button")
  },

  init: function () {
    instance = this;
    settings = this.settings;
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  swap: function (currentSide, desiredSide) {
    settings.container.toggleClass("flip");

    currentSide.fadeOut(900);
    currentSide.hide();

    desiredSide.show();
  },

  bindUIActions: function () {
    settings.days.on("click", function () {
      instance.swap(settings.calendar, settings.form);
      settings.input.focus();
    });

    settings.buttons.on("click", function () {
      instance.swap(settings.form, settings.calendar);
    });
  }
};

app.init();
</script>
```

```css
<style type = "text/css">

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #dfebed;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.calendar {
  background: #2b4450;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 501px;
  perspective: 1000;
  transition: 0.9s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Front - Calendar */
.front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.current-date {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.current-date h1 {
  color: #dfebed;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.week-days {
  color: #dfebed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.weeks {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.weeks div {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.last-month {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.weeks span {
  padding: 10px;
}

.weeks span.active {
  background: #f78536;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.weeks span:not(.last-month):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.event {
  position: relative;
}

.event:after {
  content: "•";
  color: #f78536;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: -4px;
}

/* Back - Event form */

.back {
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back input {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
  color: #dfebed;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.info {
  color: #dfebed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.info div:not(.observations) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.info span {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.info .date {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info .date p {
  width: 50%;
}

.info .address p {
  width: 100%;
}

.actions {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.actions button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 50%;
}

.actions button:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
}

.actions button:hover {
  background: #497285;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.actions button:active {
  background: #5889a0;
  outline: none;
}

/* Flip animation */

.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

</style>
```

```html
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="current-date">
        <h1>Monday 26th</h1>
        <h1>April 2021</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="current-month">
        <ul class="week-days">
          <li>MON</li>
          <li>TUE</li>
          <li>WED</li>
          <li>THU</li>
          <li>FRI</li>
          <li>SAT</li>
          <li>SUN</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="weeks">
          <div class="first">
            <span class="last-month">28</span>
            <span class="last-month">29</span>
            <span class="last-month">30</span>
            <span class="last-month">31</span>
            <span>01</span>
            <span>02</span>
            <span>03</span>
          </div>

          <div class="second">
            <span>04</span>
            <span>05</span>
            <span class="event">06</span>
            <span>07</span>
            <span>08</span>
            <span>09</span>
            <span>10</span>
          </div>

          <div class="third">
            <span>11</span>
            <span>12</span>
            <span>13</span>
            <span>14</span>
            <span class="active">15</span>
            <span>16</span>
            <span>17</span>
          </div>

          <div class="fourth">
            <span>18</span>
            <span>19</span>
            <span>20</span>
            <span>21</span>
            <span>22</span>
            <span>23</span>
            <span>24</span>
          </div>

          <div class="fifth">
            <span>25</span>
            <span>26</span>
            <span>27</span>
            <span>28</span>
            <span>29</span>
            <span>30</span>
            <span>31</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <input placeholder="What's the event?">
      <div class="info">
        <div class="date">
          <p class="info-date">
            Date: <span>Jan 15th, 2016</span>
          </p>
          <p class="info-time">
            Time: <span>6:35 PM</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <p>
            Address: <span>129 W 81st St, New York, NY</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="observations">
          <p>
            Observations: <span>Be there 15 minutes earlier</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <button class="save">
          Save <i class="ion-checkmark"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="dismiss">
          Dismiss <i class="ion-android-close"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `<script>` tag as shown below. I added Google CDN for jQuery. [Why?](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp#:%7E:text=One%20big%20advantage%20of%20using%20the%20hosted%20jQuery%20from%20Google%3A&text=Also%2C%20most%20CDN%27s%20will%20make,leads%20to%20faster%20loading%20time.) 
For more about how to load script tags [check here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/script-tag#:%7E:text=The%20browser%20loads%20all%20the,required%20while%20window%20is%20loading.)

```js
var app = {
  settings: {
    container: $(".calendar"),
    calendar: $(".front"),
    days: $(".weeks span"),
    form: $(".back"),
    input: $(".back input"),
    buttons: $(".back button")
  },

  init: function () {
    instance = this;
    settings = this.settings;
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  swap: function (currentSide, desiredSide) {
    settings.container.toggleClass("flip");

    currentSide.fadeOut(900);
    currentSide.hide();

    desiredSide.show();
  },

  bindUIActions: function () {
    settings.days.on("click", function () {
      instance.swap(settings.calendar, settings.form);
      settings.input.focus();
    });

    settings.buttons.on("click", function () {
      instance.swap(settings.form, settings.calendar);
    });
  }
};

app.init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #dfebed;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.calendar {
  background: #2b4450;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 501px;
  perspective: 1000;
  transition: 0.9s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Front - Calendar */
.front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.current-date {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.current-date h1 {
  color: #dfebed;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.week-days {
  color: #dfebed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.weeks {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.weeks div {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.last-month {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.weeks span {
  padding: 10px;
}

.weeks span.active {
  background: #f78536;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.weeks span:not(.last-month):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.event {
  position: relative;
}

.event:after {
  content: "•";
  color: #f78536;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: -4px;
}

/* Back - Event form */

.back {
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back input {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
  color: #dfebed;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.info {
  color: #dfebed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.info div:not(.observations) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.info span {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.info .date {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info .date p {
  width: 50%;
}

.info .address p {
  width: 100%;
}

.actions {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.actions button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 50%;
}

.actions button:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(73, 114, 133, 0.6);
}

.actions button:hover {
  background: #497285;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.actions button:active {
  background: #5889a0;
  outline: none;
}

/* Flip animation */

.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="current-date">
        <h1>Monday 26th</h1>
        <h1>April 2021</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="current-month">
        <ul class="week-days">
          <li>MON</li>
          <li>TUE</li>
          <li>WED</li>
          <li>THU</li>
          <li>FRI</li>
          <li>SAT</li>
          <li>SUN</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="weeks">
          <div class="first">
            <span class="last-month">28</span>
            <span class="last-month">29</span>
            <span class="last-month">30</span>
            <span class="last-month">31</span>
            <span>01</span>
            <span>02</span>
            <span>03</span>
          </div>

          <div class="second">
            <span>04</span>
            <span>05</span>
            <span class="event">06</span>
            <span>07</span>
            <span>08</span>
            <span>09</span>
            <span>10</span>
          </div>

          <div class="third">
            <span>11</span>
            <span>12</span>
            <span>13</span>
            <span>14</span>
            <span class="active">15</span>
            <span>16</span>
            <span>17</span>
          </div>

          <div class="fourth">
            <span>18</span>
            <span>19</span>
            <span>20</span>
            <span>21</span>
            <span>22</span>
            <span>23</span>
            <span>24</span>
          </div>

          <div class="fifth">
            <span>25</span>
            <span>26</span>
            <span>27</span>
            <span>28</span>
            <span>29</span>
            <span>30</span>
            <span>31</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <input placeholder="What's the event?">
      <div class="info">
        <div class="date">
          <p class="info-date">
            Date: <span>Jan 15th, 2016</span>
          </p>
          <p class="info-time">
            Time: <span>6:35 PM</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <p>
            Address: <span>129 W 81st St, New York, NY</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="observations">
          <p>
            Observations: <span>Be there 15 minutes earlier</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <button class="save">
          Save <i class="ion-checkmark"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="dismiss">
          Dismiss <i class="ion-android-close"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```